# What is the point of being able to hide a community on your profile when people can see it anyways?

Tags: support, linked-accounts, recent-activity, privacy, hidden-communities

Click:

Profile -> View network profile -> accounts or activity

Any community you've selected to "hide" from actually is not hidden here; it's completely public. I logged out and tested it on my own profile and nothing is actually hidden.

So, what's the point...? I'd really like to not have my profile tied to certain communities where things are more personal but I really don't want to have to make a separate account and lose my previous points/badges.

Comment: Easy: there is none.

Comment: The point is to remove certain distracting posts and accounts from the view of an entirely casual passersby. No protection is offered against anyone with any degree of curiosity, and since visiting a profile implies a certain degree of curiosity, there's very little protection indeed.